# Issue in posting the php file

Tags: php, html, post, xampp

I'm trying to insert data that is collected through html form and just show that data after submitting is added successfully but the problem is when ever I click submit button, the php file that I linked it with the action form is shown instead of saying data is added successfully.

Here's the error:

[image]

html code of this:

https://gist.github.com/Sarathchandra1202/72c1c26d70b4d24aa65f64858ec84f9c

php code of this : https://gist.github.com/Sarathchandra1202/590e46fd9ed9983929c9ba1bc38fac94

please can you tell me where im going wrong

My database:

[image]

My folder which contains all the files:

[image: its located in : "C:\Users\sunny\Desktop\vvmatrimony"]

Comment: This is because you are opening the file directly. Open the file via the Server side using XAMPP/WAMP/ Vhosts, etc.

Comment: Hmm let me try, if possible can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: You have XAMPP/ WAMP installed? Please google how to install and run php on windows via XAMPP/ WAMP.

Comment: yes i have xampp installed and its running

Comment: apache and mysql is running already and i already created the database and the required tables

Comment: Open the URL via `localhost/<your_folder_name>/file`

Comment: I have updated the question with more data can you please look into it @SachinBahukhandi

Comment: Please make the address bar for the system folder visible.

Comment: I have updated the photo in the question

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi Please look into it

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), nor should we have to follow links to see it. The question should contain a [mre] and text explaining the problem.

Comment: ok, sorry for not posting my question properly, ill keep this in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the form using the following URL:

http://localhost/vvmatrimony/<your_file.html>

Ideally this should work.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked but there's an other issue it says
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Table 'vvmat.profilee' doesn't exist in D:\xampp\htdocs\vvmatrimony\registeration.php:42 Stack trace: #0 D:\xampp\htdocs\vvmatrimony\registeration.php(42): mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO pro...') #1 {main} thrown in D:\xampp\htdocs\vvmatrimony\registeration.php on line 42

How can i solve this? @Sachin Bahukhandi

Comment: Welcome. Also, the error suggests the table does not exist.

Comment: Fixed it, it was a typo :) Thank you